# How to style an embedded jsp inside another jsp?

Tags: css, jsp

I am a css/javascript beginner. How would I access an HTML element of a jsp that's embedded inside another jsp and css style it? I am not allowed to modify the first one directly, so I was wondering if I could style it from within the second one.

Comment: CSS doesn't see JSP. CSS only sees HTML in webbrowser which is been sent by JSP in webserver. It's unclear what JSP composition you're talking about. Please open the JSP in your browser, rightclick it and choose *View Source*. Then extract the relevant part from it which you'd like to style so that we can suggest the proper CSS approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you can access your Html by Tag or Attributes (class,id,rel...)

Maybe this is your Html...

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

And now you can access your Html with various selectors:

```
/*CSS*/
div {color:red}
div > p {color:blue}
.para {color:green}
#content .para {background:red}
```

<strike>Good</strike> ressource: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp